# how to retrieve filename from input type=file value

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function for validating image files uploaded through this:

```
<input accept="image/*" type="file" name="temp_picture" id="temp_picture">
//onchange
validate($(this).attr('name')); //I had to use the attribute name in some other function
```

And then I have this checker in a function if it is a valid jpeg/jpg file

```
function validate(pictureId){
    var fileExtension = document.getElementById(pictureId).value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    //etc
}
```

The problem is, I could not get the image filename from value. The code below returns an empty string:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(pictureId).value);
```

Comment: // get the file name, possibly with path (depends on browser)
        var filename = $("#temp_picture").val();

        // Use a regular expression to trim everything before final dot
        var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');

Comment: It returns an empty string

$('#temp_picture');
[
<input accept=​"image/​*" type=​"file" name=​"temp_picture" id=​"temp_picture">
]
$('#temp_picture').val();
""

Comment: I think I've figured out the problem.
When the function validate() is called, the input [type=image] doesn't have a value yet because it is still getting the image file uploaded to it. So it calls the function without having the contents yet that's why it doesn't have any value yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the "filelist" api, like this:

```
var file = document.getElementById( 'temp_picture' ).files[0];
alert(file.name);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList


HTML
----
    <form id='bob'>
        <input accept="image/*" type="file" name="temp_picture" id="temp_picture" multiple>
        <div id='output'></div>
    </form>


Javascript
----------
        function getvalues(){

            var output=document.getElementById('output');
            var input=document.getElementById('temp_picture');

            input.onchange=function(e){
                var files=input.files;
                for( var i=0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
                    createNode( 'pre',{ innerHTML:'Name='+files[i].name+'<br />Size='+files[i].size+'<br />Type='+files[i].type, style:'margin:3em' }, output );
                }
            }
        }
/*
There is a function here called 'createNode' - basically it uses document.createElement but also adds attributes to newly generated nodes. I have not included it for reasons of brevity.
*/

 window.onload=getvalues;
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, could you tell me how to use those web api interfaces? I tried inputting your code directly into the console but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses the undefined identifier `pictureId`. Use the string `'#temp_picture'` instead.

If you actually had `var pictureId = '#temp_picture'` but forgot to include it in the code you posted, the odds are that the code is being executed before the user made any selection. It works if you execute the code e.g. in an `onchange` even handler.

Note that the name returned is usually not the true pathname of the file but could be e.g. `C:\fakepath\foo.png`. This is a security measure, intended to prevent pages from inspecting the file system of the user’s computer. Here it does not matter, since you apparently want to look just at the last few characters of the name.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how I did it, it takes into consideration of the `\fakepath\`, it also fetches both the extension and the filename:

```
document.getElementById("temp_picture").onchange=function(){
  var removeFakePath = this.value.split("\\"); // For the browser that add a fake path
  var getFileWithExt = removeFakePath[removeFakePath.length - 1];
  var splitExtension = getFileWithExt.split(".");
  var filename = splitExtension[0];
  var extension = splitExtension[1];
    alert("Filename:" + filename + "\n\rExtension:" + extension);
};
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6tyaY/2/)

Comment: This is great. But do all browsers add fakepaths?

Comment: @Cynara No, but it doesn't matter if it has the `/fakepath/` or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have given your id wrong in the function..Thats the main problem for the error message.

I am attaching a demo here satisfying your requirements.Do check.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QlGMSL6xJulxBSPBbB1f?p=preview

Comment: I'm sorry how do you think I've made a mistake in using the id?
And I could not find the answer you gave

Comment: well temp_picture is your id for the input tag and you used pictureId in document.getElementBYID. You can see the answer in console .Anyways now i have modified it and the answer comes in alert.Do check

Answer (score 1):

```
write the following function on the click event of button or something you are going to use

function checkvalid()
{
   var file_name = document.getElementById("temp_picture").value;
   var file_extn=file_name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
   switch(file_extn) {
        //if .jpg/.gif/.png do something
        case 'jpg': case 'gif': case 'png':

            /* handle */
            break;
        //if .zip/.rar do something else
        case 'zip': case 'rar':
            /* handle */`enter code here`
            break;

        //if .pdf do something else
        case 'pdf':
            /* handle */
            break;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. My code is attached to the 'change' event. The problem is, I could not get that 'file_extn' value. That code is just the same as mine so it will still not work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out below code for your help:

It check s the file size and file type

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelected();">`
`<script>
var iMaxFilesize = 1048576; // 1MB
function fileSelected()
{
// get selected file element
var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file').files[0];
// filter for image files
var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    alert("Not a proper file format");
    return;
}
// little test for filesize
if (oFile.size > iMaxFilesize) {
    alert("File size exceeded");
    return;
}
alert("success = "+oFile.name);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```